# На кого рассчитывать ответ?

Tags: обсуждение, ответы

Я постоянно в практике своей сталкиваюсь с людьми, работающими по принципу "и так сойдёт", это касается и их кода.

На SO очень часто вопросы задают новички, которые "только учатся", которым "не нужен сложный код, надо, чтоб хоть как-то работало".

И вот на такие вопросы не совсем ясно, в каком виде всё-таки отвечать. Можно написать самый простой вариант, который работает, да, автор даже будет доволен и заапрувит ответ, но... объективно у ответа могут быть проблемы:

1. Проблемы с оптимизацией
2. Проблемы с читаемостью
3. Проблемы в плане паттернов

И вот интересно, на какой уровень людей вы ориентируетесь, давая ответы? Пишете более-менее рабочий ответ по принципу "чтоб работало" или пытаетесь применить свой опыт и написать хороший, правильный ответ, но при этом автор вопроса может его не понять.

Если сюда ещё присовокупить все обсуждения на мете по поводу качества ответов, мол ответ — это долгосрочная перспектива, чтоб в будущем помочь и другим людям, то совсем неясно. Интересно бы было услышать ваши рассуждения на этот счёт.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

В первую очередь надо понять, для кого вы пишете ответ.

1. Если вопрос какой-то специфический, и его пишет профессионал, то и ответ можно дать специфический, без особого объяснения ("вызовите эту функцию, именно её вам не хватает для счастья"). Специалист справится с прочтением справки и поиском статей, часто достаточно дать зацепку.
2. Если вопрос потенциально полезен широкой аудитории, то имеет смысл написать полноценный ответ с разбором ("вызовите эту функцию, это вам даст то-то и то-то в таких-то и таких-то условиях по той-то и той-то причине").
3. Если вопрос полезен очень широкой аудитории, то имеет смысл разобрать потенциальные проблемы с решением, неочевидные ситуации и тому подобное ("если вы вызовете эту функцию, у вас могут быть проблемы с тем-то и тем-то, и это так-то и так-то скажется на архитектуре вашего приложения").

Это с точки зрения оптимального использования ресурсов. Разумеется, вы можете делать полный разбор в абсолютно всех случаях, но вряд ли вас хватит надолго, поэтому уж лучше потратьте своё время с большей эффективностью.

---

Особняком стоят вопросы от новичков. В их случае могут потребоваться объяснения даже специфических вопросов. Также может иметь смысл разобрать проблемы с кодом, напрямую не связанные с обсуждаемой проблемой. По сути, приходится делать полноценный разбор, как при ответе для широкой аудитории, но ради одного человека. Здесь уже смотрите, сколько вы готовы потратить времени на одного новичка, и насколько мир станет от этого лучше.

Часто по новичку видно, то ли он хочет научиться программировать, то ли сдать домашнюю работу на хорошо. Думаю, это подходящий ориентир.

Answer (score 14):

Мне кажется, хороший ответ, в отличие от «просто ответа», должен нести определённую воспитательную роль, объяснять, как прежде всего нужно думать, а затем уже о том, как решить техническую мелкую проблему.

Если есть шанс научить чему-то текущих и будущих читателей, почему бы не сделать это? Да, это сложнее, зато ценность ответа сразу намного выше.

Но на многие вопросы, по сути, невозможно дать обучающий ответ. Здесь уж приходится ограничивать ответ рамками вопроса.

Answer (score 11):

Ничего плохого в том, что вы напишете больше, нет. Наоборот, это хорошо. Если автор вопроса проигнорирует ваши дополнения, то все равно найдутся читатели, которым это будет полезно.

Я (да и некоторые другие участники, как я замечал) поступаю так: сперва отвечаю непосредственно на вопрос, потом вставляю горизонтальную линию и после нее уже пишу все замечания и дополнения, не касающиеся непосредственно вопроса.

Answer (score 9):

Я крайне редко пишу 100% работоспособный код, которые сразу можно *copy-paste* и сразу же заработает. Тому есть 2 причины:

1. Я все таки не теряю надежды дать новичку возможность поработать самому головой. Чтобы головной мозг не атрофировался. Даже если дать работосособный код - то возникает тема описываемая п. 2.
2. Опыт показывает, что даже если сделать 100% работоспособный код, то сразу возникает масса вопросов по его применению к конкретной ситуации - то есть вместо ответа я получаю тучу комментариев, а то и пару новых вопросов.

Именно поэтому я стараюсь давать ответ, где расписаны основные вехи с небольшими вставками кода, а то и просто методами/функциями, которые можно применить в данной ситуации.

Answer (score 6):

Здесь вам не twitter, ограничения на максимальную длину сообщения на этом сайте нет.
Почему бы не включать в свои ответы оба варианта - и быстрый и правильный (с Вашей точки зрения)

Comment: Просто порой ответ бывает короче, чем минимальная длина сообщения( Особенно если это ссылка/картинка/число. на хешкоде мне это не мешало, а тут порой приходится мучительно думать, какой воды налить в ответ

Answer (score 5):

Мне кажется ответ на вопрос должен быть максимально верным не зависимо от его сложности, если автор запросит более простое решение то можно дать и его. Дело в том что ресурс хорошо гуглится и очень часто его можно увидеть в поисковой выдаче, так что зачастую автор ответа не единственный кто получит данное вами решение. 
Верные и правильные решения в такой ситуации очень важны, многие действительно учатся при помощи гугла, а неправильные решения в такой ситуации обязательно скажутся на качестве обучения)

Answer (score 3):

Считаю важным найти оптимальный вариант или реанимировать пусть нерабочее, но красивое решение. Не только учить, но и учиться самому.

Answer (score 3):

Вы же и для себя тоже пишете ответ. Если ответ вам самому не нравится, то смысл его писать?