# Выборы модераторов сообщества 2015: ответы кандидатов на вопросы сообщества

Tags: обсуждение, выборы

В дополнение к выборам модераторов мы проводим секцию вопросов и ответов с кандидатами. [Вопросы кандидатам](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2028/) обсуждались в отдельной публикации. Как говорилось ранее, из всех мы отобрали 8 вопросов от участников сообщества с наибольшим количеством голосов «за» и дополнили их двумя обязательными.

### Ссылки на ответы кандидатов:

<sub>(В хронологическом порядке)</sub>

- [Risto](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2148/)
- [Suvitruf](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2150/)
- [Discord](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2152/)
- [alexander barakin](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2153/)
- [Qwertiy](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2154/)
- [PashaPash](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2161/)
- [Nick Volynkin](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2164/)
- [Nofate](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2184)

### Инструкция для кандидатов

Ваша задача, как кандидата, очень проста – опубликовать в ответ *на этот вопрос* ваши ответы на все вопросы итогового списка вопросов кандидату. Пожалуйста, добавьте имя автора (ваше) в самом начале ответа, чтобы другие участники понимали, чьи ответы они читают в данный момент. Пожалуйста, используйте форматирование как в этой публикации для выделения вопросов и ваших ответов к ним.

Как только все кандидаты разместят свои ответы, мы будем использовать данную публикацию как основу для принятия решений, чтобы каждый участник, который будет голосовать, понимал, за кого он отдает свой голос.

Удачи, кандидаты!

### Вопросы

> Как вы поступите с участником, который создает большое количество ценных ответов, но порождает массу споров в комментариях, которые впоследствии отмечаются сигналом тревоги?

---

> Как вы поступите в ситуации, когда другой модератор закроет, удалит и т. д. вопрос, который, по вашему мнению, не стоит закрывать, удалять и т. д.?

---

> Работать на благо сообщества вы можете и без статуса модератора. Так зачем вы действительно решили стать модератором?

---

> Есть ли правила сайта, в том числе принятые сообществом на Мете, с которыми вы не согласны? Если да, то какие, и как вы собираетесь действовать?

---

> Есть ли сообщение на Мете (вопрос или ответ), которым вы гордитесь? С какой целью вы его опубликовали и насколько эта цель была достигнута?

---

> Какие основные недостатки и проблемы вы видите в сайте на сегодняшний день? Как они мешают развитию сообщества? Как вы собираетесь с ними бороться?

---

> Проблема была вынесена на Мету, сообщество приняло решение, но вы с ним категорически не согласны. Как вы будете действовать?
>
> <sub>Примеры: разрешать или запрещать вопросы по какой-то тематике, разрешать или запрещать скопированное содержимое без ссылок, удалить или оставить метку и т. п.</sub>

---

> Достаточно многие русскоязычные специалисты принципиально пользуются StackOverflow на английском (en.SO). Среди них есть как просто ищущие ответы, так и активные участники. Свое предпочтение они аргументируют примерно так (все примеры из личного опыта):
>
> - На en.SO больше ответов и отвечающих, а на ru.SO мало участников, долго дают ответ
> - На ru.SO мало интересных вопросов, не на что отвечать
> - Английский — язык профессионального общения, поэтому нужно спрашивать на нем
> - SO на русском не нужен
> - Я не знаю, что есть SO на русском
>
> Что бы вы на это возразили? Как можно привлечь русскоязычных программистов и системных администраторов к участию именно в StackOverflow на русском?

---

> Как вы собираетесь действовать в ситуации, когда трактовка одного или нескольких правил (официальных или принятых на Мете) одного из участников или группы участников расходится с вашим пониманием этих же правил?

---

> Вы получаете большое количество тревог о спорных результатах проверки. Значительная часть их них сгенерирована одним из топовых участников, причем он явно голосует вразрез с решениями на мете. При попытке выяснить причину вы слышите от него "мои голоса, использую их как хочу". Ваши действия?

Comment: Дорогие кандидаты, напомню, что [здесь](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/2028/10105) лежат ещё много вопросов, не попавших в топ. Если вы захотите ответить на какой-то из них тоже, вы вполне можете включить их в свой ответ.

Comment: Ох, сколько же букафф... Мало того, что прочитать надо, так ещё и самому писать)

Comment: Вопросы -   почти одна банальщина.  Даже не интересно ответы читать, потому что в общем и так ясно какие они будут.

Comment: @semiromid: Где ж вы были, когда все задавали вопросы?

Comment: VladD - Я был со всеми, и активно участвовал в проведенном мероприятии.

Comment: Вот если бы еще кандидаты не читали ответов других, а то популизм получается и единство позиций

Comment: @KromStern: мы близки во мнениях очень по многим вопросам. А на те темы, где разногласия, вопросов не задано. Например, мы с Discord очень разного мнения о необходимой мере вмешательства модератора, мы спорили в комментариях под заявками.

Answer (score 11):

## [Discord](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/176051/discord)

> Как вы поступите с участником, который создает большое количество ценных ответов, но порождает массу споров в комментариях, которые впоследствии отмечаются сигналом тревоги?

Споры спорам рознь. Если кто-то очень чувствительно реагирует на адекватную критику ("так делать неправильно, надо так") и отмечает тревогами всё подряд — это одно дело, если высокореповый участник откровенно провоцирует конфликты с переходом на личности — это другое. Слишком много условий, и от них зависят действия: где-то надо связаться с одним, где-то с другим, где-то с обоими; дальше идут словесные предупреждения; в особо тяжёлых случаях может понадобиться и временный бан.

В конечном счёте, неприкосновенных нет. Даже если у участника 100К репутации, он может быть забанен на какое-то время, чтобы остыть и подумать о своём поведении. Нарушение правил есть нарушение, и ценные ответы не могут служить оправданием. Появление "высшей касты" может привести к гораздо большему вреду, чем обида одного конфликтного участника: уйдёт не один "супер-участник", а 20 "средних".

---

> Как вы поступите в ситуации, когда другой модератор закроет, удалит и т. д. вопрос, который, по вашему мнению, не стоит закрывать, удалять и т. д.?

Если в модераторы не попадут участники с радикальными взглядами на закрытие (вплоть до игнорирования правил), то такая ситуация — это исключение и большая редкость. Дальше в зависимости от аргументации другого модератора и уверенности нас обоих в своей правоте, по нарастающей: личное обсуждение, обсуждение в чате, обсуждение на Мете. Обсуждение на Мете может возникнуть при разной интерпретации правил, например — в этом случае будет оправдано публичное обсуждение ситуации, с удалённым вопросом в качестве примера. Плюс, насколько я слышал, также есть модераторский чат — можно воспользоваться и им, если это целесообразно.

---

> Работать на благо сообщества вы можете и без статуса модератора. Так зачем вы действительно решили стать модератором?

Да, как обычный пользователь с модераторскими привилегиями (10К), я уже имею обширные возможности для организации данных и чистки мусора, но у избираемых модераторов возможности шире: я смогу чистить комментарии, переименовывать и синонимизировать метки, закрывать и удалять старые оффтопичные вопросы, объединять дубликаты и совершать прочие операции самостоятельно.

Например, когда я искал грубости и оскорбления в комментариях с помощью запросов на Data.SE, то сотни тревог в день доставались на проверку Nofate — это банально двойная работа. Также после поднятия порогов привилегий участников, пользующихся инструментами модераторов, которые доступны на 10К, практически не осталось. Это означает, что удаление оффтопичных и флудовых вопросов без вмешательства ромбов стало практически невозможным, равно как и слежение за вопросами, выкинутыми из очередей проверок с большим количеством голосов на закрытие, например.

---

> Есть ли правила сайта, в том числе принятые сообществом на Мете, с которыми вы не согласны? Если да, то какие, и как вы собираетесь действовать?

Я не в восторге от включения в Stack Overflow на русском тематики Server Fault, но это меньшее из зол, и нормальной альтернативы нет (и, видимо, не будет в обозримом будущем). Это решение принято в большой мере администрацией, поэтому сообщество, по большому счёту, повлиять на него не может (у нас на Ru.SO этот конфликт явно не проявлялся, но история помнит две закрытые заявки Pt.SF на Area 51 с сопутствующими драмами). В целом, проблемы как таковой нет, надо лишь следить, чтобы остальные несогласные со включением тематики Server Fault не увлекались и не закрывали официально разрешённые вопросы с пользовательскими причинами закрытия в стиле "сисадминство тут оффтопик".

---

> Есть ли сообщение на Мете (вопрос или ответ), которым вы гордитесь? С какой целью вы его опубликовали и насколько эта цель была достигнута?

Мне сложно назвать один пост, Мета слишком разнообразна. Народ оценил мой пост [Долой [программирование]!](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/52/%d0%94%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5) 40 плюсами, но это служебный пост, да и чисткой в большой мере занимаюсь я же. Из-за меня [надпись "заморжен" на вопросах поменялась на "требует правки"](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/393/%d0%a5%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%8b), но при очевидных плюсах этот пост открыл ящик Пандоры. Я начал процесс [включения тематики Code Review](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1761/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2-%d1%81-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-code-review/1762#1762), но процесс ещё не завершён, и вопросов с меткой [инспекция-кода](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0) пока мало. Я много [боролся за правильные причины закрытия](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1924/%d0%92%d1%8b-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b9-stackoverflow-%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-1-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b6%d0%bd%d1%8b-%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%8c), и результат достигнут, но это не моя работа, а коллективная: обсуждение происходило во многих местах. Я часто писал подробные [инструкции для новчиков](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/428/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%83-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8f-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b5-%d0%b1%d1%8b%d0%bb-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd-%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%be%d1%82%d1%81/429#429)... В целом, я не могу привести какой-нибудь один мега-эпический пост и сказать: "Вот он — венец моего творения!" Мета — это живой коллективный организм, решения принимаются совместно, инструкции пишутся совместно, и я лишь его часть.

---

> Какие основные недостатки и проблемы вы видите в сайте на сегодняшний день? Как они мешают развитию сообщества? Как вы собираетесь с ними бороться?

Я против слишком кардинального изменения формулировок причин закрытия относительно оригинала, которое было проведено с минимальным одобрением на Мете. Результатом является закрытие вопросов с причинами "от балды", когда ни закрывающий не уверен в причине, ни автор вопроса не понимает, как реагировать на закрытие. На данный момент сообщество добилось уничтожения причины закрытия "опросник", которая дублировала существующие причины закрытия и была причиной закрытия многих "неугодных" по личным мотивам вопросов. Работа будет продолжаться. Собственно, собираюсь и дальше писать на Мете огромные посты с аргументацией своей позиции, а также дискутировать в чате.

Есть огромная проблема с индексацией Яндексом, но это вне моей компетенции, этой проблемой занимается Николас.

Остальные проблемы в основном "рабочие", то есть они хорошо известны, по ним выработаны процедуры, работа ведётся непрерывно, каких-то кардинальных действий не требуется. Скажем, некачественные вопросы от новичков — это вечная проблема, но всем хорошо понятно, что надо делать, чтобы минимизировать последствия.

---

> Проблема была вынесена на Мету, сообщество приняло решение, но вы с ним категорически не согласны. Как вы будете действовать?
>
> <sub>Примеры: разрешать или запрещать вопросы по какой-то тематике, разрешать или запрещать скопированное содержимое без ссылок, удалить или оставить метку и т. п.</sub>

Соглашаться буду, что ещё можно сделать... Здесь надо отметить, что решения не вечные, и при достаточной аргументации и упорстве на них можно повлиять. Поэтому, если будет что сказать аргументированного, то буду писать на Мету и отстаивать свою позицию. Разумеется, при этом на основном сайте я буду соблюдать решение сообщества. Также должен отметить, что в ранге "категорически не согласен" у меня на данный момент только одно решение, поэтому это скорее исключение, а не закономерность, и не представляет каких-либо серьёзных трудностей.

---

> Достаточно многие русскоязычные специалисты принципиально пользуются StackOverflow на английском (en.SO). Среди них есть как просто ищущие ответы, так и активные участники. Свое предпочтение они аргументируют примерно так (все примеры из личного опыта):
>
> - На en.SO больше ответов и отвечающих, а на ru.SO мало участников, долго дают ответ
> - На ru.SO мало интересных вопросов, не на что отвечать
> - Английский — язык профессионального общения, поэтому нужно спрашивать на нем
> - SO на русском не нужен
> - Я не знаю, что есть SO на русском
>
> Что бы вы на это возразили? Как можно привлечь русскоязычных программистов и системных администраторов к участию именно в StackOverflow на русском?

Словами на сайт никого не загонишь, нужно доказывать действиями. А это значит, что наполнение и активность на сайте должны привлекать как экспертов, так и новичков. "Дворником-организатором" на сайте работаю как раз по этой причине:

- способствую закрытию и удалению старых вопросов с флудом и оффтопиком, чтобы эксперты видели качественные вопросы, а не мусор, а новички брали пример с хороших вопросов и не аргументировали "а вон там похожий вопрос задали, почему мне нельзя?";
- привожу в порядок метки, чтобы было легче найти нужную информацию, чтобы новичкам было сложнее ошибиться в выборе меток, чтобы эксперты не боялись пропустить вопросы по интересным им темам;
- переношу картинки и код со внешних ресурсов, чтобы не было вопросов и ответов с умершей информацией;
- и так далее.

Сайт постоянно растёт, и важно, чтобы зашедшие на него однажды оценили его по достоинству. Тогда будет больше и задающих вопросы, и отвечающих, а соответственно, и интересных вопросов, и интересных ответов.

Если бы английский был всемирным языком, на котором *свободно* общались все и каждый на всей планете, сайт был бы не нужен. Но пока это не так. Так что на ближайшие лет 100–200 посетителями сайт обеспечен, а там видно будет.

---

> Как вы собираетесь действовать в ситуации, когда трактовка одного или нескольких правил (официальных или принятых на Мете) одного из участников или группы участников расходится с вашим пониманием этих же правил?

Обсуждать в личных сообщениях (если проблема не в трактовке правила, а в активном применении), обсуждать в чате (можно быстро оценить ситуацию, много активных пользователей), обсуждать на Мете (если это важный вопрос).

Ещё можно заметить, что кроме понимания правил мной и другими участниками есть движок сайта, у которого тоже есть "мнение". Движок умеет автоматически раздавать баны в правках, в проверках и так далее, когда считает это целесообразным. То есть даже активные действия не всегда требуются, система умеет защищаться сама.

---

> Вы получаете большое количество тревог о спорных результатах проверки. Значительная часть их них сгенерирована одним из топовых участников, причем он явно голосует вразрез с решениями на мете. При попытке выяснить причину вы слышите от него "мои голоса, использую их как хочу". Ваши действия?

Зависит от серьёзности конфликтов. Скажем, если участник голосует за спорные и неоднозначные вопросы вразрез с большинством, то это нормально, это мнение, и он имеет на это полное право (обычно в таких случаях он будет не единственным, проголосовавшим вразрез с мнением большинства). Если же участник голосует за закрытие очень качественных вопросов или открытие откровенного флуда, причём делает это систематически, то это повод для обсуждения ситуации в личных сообщениях, в особо тяжёлых случаях — в бане. Бан может понадобиться в том случае, когда действия приносят реальный вред, то есть влияют на результаты голосования, например, когда возникает сговор. Часто подобное поведение можно игнорировать, потому что большинство обычно голосует верно.

Большую часть подобных нарушений обнаруживает система с помощью проверок, однако её очень легко обойти, поэтому надо смотреть, как много из голосов вразрез могли бы быть сочтены проваленными проверками. Если участник приноровился обходить проверки, это не значит, что он получил право игнорировать правила. Нужно смотреть по ситуации.

В целом, пользователь должен понимать, что при несогласии с правилами нужно выносить обсуждение на Мету и аргументировать позицию, а не партизанить в очередях проверок, хорошо понимая, что он голосует не в соответствии с правилами.

Answer (score 10):

## [Nick Volynkin](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/181472/nick-volynkin)

Так уж получилось, что я писал этот ответ два часа и здесь очень много текста. Это потому что вопросы важные, но сложные, и я не могу ответить одной строчкой из правил.

---

> Как вы поступите с участником, который создает большое количество ценных ответов, но порождает массу споров в комментариях, которые впоследствии отмечаются сигналом тревоги?

Споры бывают разные. Участники тоже бывают разные.

- Если споры по предмету вопроса — пускай спорят. Это гораздо лучше, чем когда эксперт равнодушно закрывает вопрос, который ему не нравится или недостаточно хорошо оформлен. Но такие споры не провоцируют сигналов тревоги.
- Если споры по теме сайта, но не по предмету вопроса — приду и перенесу обсуждение в чат, где ему и место. Насколько я помню, бывает даже блокировка вопроса или ответа от комментариев. Это можно применить в крайнем случае, если участники игнорируют даже перемещение в чат.
- Если споры идут с переходом на личные качества участников, то мне придется на краткое время заблокировать вопрос/ответ и лично обратиться к тому, кто нарушает правила сайта. Я буду рассчитывать на конструктивный разговор и постараюсь объяснить, почему на ru.SO (да и во всей сети сайтов) недопустимы оскорбления и другие проявления неуважения. Бывает, что человек просто сорвался, но в целом адекватен. *Идеальный исход конфликта — когда участники успокаиваются сразу, жмут руки (виртуально) и расходятся.*

  - Если я встречу понимание, то участник останется с предупреждением, но без ограничительных мер. Через день я проверю новые сообщения этого участника.
  - Если не встречу — применю особую модераторскую магию «чтобы успокоиться».
  - В любом случае я проверю другие комментарии участника за последние несколько дней.
  - Наверное, отпишусь в какой-нибудь модераторский канал связи, чтобы обстоятельства конфликта сохранились для истории. Не знаю, как оно там устроено и как мы договоримся обмениваться информацией.

---

> Как вы поступите в ситуации, когда другой модератор закроет, удалит и т. д. вопрос, который, по вашему мнению, не стоит закрывать, удалять и т. д.?

Моя реакция зависит от меры того, насколько расходятся наши мнения. Со всеми лидерами первого тура голосования мы близки во мнениях о допустимой тематике и стандартах качества вопросов. Но если всё же я буду категорически не согласен с закрытием или удалением, то обсужу этот вопрос в модераторском кругу (то есть со всеми четверыми, учитывая Nicolas). Если дискуссия приведет нас к пониманию того, что в правилах сообщества есть дыра, вынесем обсуждение на Мету и дыру пропатчим.

---

> Работать на благо сообщества вы можете и без статуса модератора. Так зачем вы действительно решили стать модератором?

Действительно, очень многое можно делать и без статуса. Но у меня была возможность воспользоваться инструментами, которые даются на высоких уровнях репутации, и именно из них я извлекал много полезной информации. Они позволяют анализировать поведение участников сайта и отслеживать важные показатели, например:

- Как редактируют сообщения? (порой, гневно) => [Всем чмоке в этой истории правок](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1159/)
- Удаляется ли спам? (не всегда) => [Спам не [требует-правки], спам требует немедленного удаления!](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/972/)
- Есть ли вопросы, по которым мнения сильно разделились? (нужно привести обсуждение в конструктивное русло) => [Давайте решим, что нам делать с вопросом о поиске работы](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1771/)

У модератора таких возможностей ещё больше. Я смогу получать оперативные данные по тому, что происходит на сайте. Смогу обращаться прямо в личном сообщении к новичкам, которые запутались в аккаунтах или в шоке от сразу закрытого первого вопроса. Смогу наводить порядок в метках, прежде всего откатывать плагиат — он чаще всего встречается именно там. По очереди тревог смогу определять и разрешать конфликтные ситуации.

---

> Есть ли правила сайта, в том числе принятые сообществом на Мете, с которыми вы не согласны? Если да, то какие, и как вы собираетесь действовать?

Я участвовал в большинстве обсуждений, а читал абсолютно все. В данный момент я согласен со всеми принятыми решениями, хотя поддерживаю их в разной степени. Но есть внутренне противоречивые решения — например про списки литературы и списки вообще. Над ними просто нужно работать дальше — улучшать качество списков литературы, улучшать описания соответствующих меток, устранять неоднозначности в правилах.

---

> Есть ли сообщение на Мете (вопрос или ответ), которым вы гордитесь? С какой целью вы его опубликовали и насколько эта цель была достигнута?

Всё-таки я [фанатик](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/55/fanatic) Меты, так что горжусь многим.

1. **Метки Меты**. Написал краткие и полные описания для более чем полусотни меток, некоторые доработал, чаще писал с нуля или опираясь на перевод. Получил на этом [научного ассистента](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/79/research-assistant). Любимая метка, в которую вложено больше всего труда: [статус-так-задумано](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%81-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be). Я досадую, что её редко ставят, хотя она уместна во многих случаях. 
   **Результат**: вся Мета размечена, в вопросах легко ориентироваться, на новые вопросы метки ставятся адекватно.
2. [Долгосрочные цели для сообщества StackOverflow на русском языке](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/955/181472). Этот вопрос помог обозначить важные векторы развития: метрика отвеченных вопросов, локализация, справочный центр. Я не утверждаю, что до этого о них никто не подозревал, совсем наоборот. Но было привлечено дополнительное внимание и даны инструкции к действию. Мы стали отслеживать свой прогресс и анализировать результаты.
   **Результат**: Позакрывали старый оффтопик и, наоборот, нашли и оценили старые хорошие вопросы. В процессе мы натренировали себе закрывашки и открывашки, рождали в спорах истину, ответили на некоторое число хороших старых вопросов.

---

> Какие основные недостатки и проблемы вы видите в сайте на сегодняшний день? Как они мешают развитию сообщества? Как вы собираетесь с ними бороться?

Сразу уточняю, что под сайтом я понимаю именно движок и прочий функционал, но не сообщество. Про проблемы в сообществе и так сказано достаточно в ответах на другие вопросы.

- Не доработана локализация сайта. Впереди перевод разделов Jobs и Documentation. Сообществу не мешает, разберемся при открытии разделов в штатном режиме.
- Не все разделы справки актуальны. Многие решения сообщества не отражены там и вообще затеряны в глубинах Меты. Это вызывает споры и непонимания. [Нужно дополнять Справку](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2094/181472) — модератор как раз имеет возможность это делать.
- Нет связей между вопросами на разных сайтах сети SE. Можно было бы хотя бы кросс-ссылки добавлять в блок связанных вопросов. Я считаю, что это поможет организации знаний. Тут нужно партизанским отрядом продвигать эту фичу на Мете SE. Ромб добавит убедительности там.
- Формулировки причин закрытия многим непонятны, либо их не читают. Другие инструкции для новичков тоже непонятны либо игнорируются. Это, пожалуй, самая сложная проблема, ее нужно решать общими усилиями. С возможностями модератора я смогу исследовать поведение новичков и связываться с ними напрямую.

---

> Проблема была вынесена на Мету, сообщество приняло решение, но вы с ним категорически не согласны. Как вы будете действовать?
>
> <sub>Примеры: разрешать или запрещать вопросы по какой-то тематике, разрешать или запрещать скопированное содержимое без ссылок, удалить или оставить метку и т. п.</sub>

Поскольку сообщество приняло это решение, я буду ему следовать. Перечитаю всё обсуждение и постараюсь понять и систематизировать аргументы участников. Если я по-прежнему не согласен и вопрос важный, то буду собирать и анализировать данные, а потом напишу на Мете новый вопрос, аргументируя свою точку зрения.

Отдельный случай: «разрешать или запрещать скопированное содержимое без ссылок». Плагиат запрещен правилами сайта и пользовательским соглашением, так что сообщество не может отменить запрет своим решением. Но это искусственная ситуация, я не представляю, что кто-то действительно будет агитировать за плагиат.

---

> Достаточно многие русскоязычные специалисты принципиально пользуются StackOverflow на английском (en.SO). Среди них есть как просто ищущие ответы, так и активные участники. Свое предпочтение они аргументируют примерно так (все примеры из личного опыта):
>
> - Английский — язык профессионального общения, поэтому нужно спрашивать на нем

В таком случае я обычно говорю, что they are absolutely free to ask and answer exclusively in English and on StackOverflow in English, but the language barrier implies its own limitations to both their ability to explain the problem and their understanding of the offered solution. I ask, if they needed to solve a problem in a real business case, would they ask their colleague in English just because it's a damn international language?

> - На en.SO больше ответов и отвечающих, а на ru.SO мало участников, долго дают ответ

Отвечающих больше, но больше и спрашивающих. К новичкам, по моей субъективной оценке, у нас отношение лучше. Есть проблема с вопросами по непопулярным темам — на них действительно сложно бывает получить ответ. Но эта проблема со временем ослабевает, т.к. на сайт приходят специалисты по разным темам. А по некоторым темам вроде 1C нужно спрашивать именно здесь.

> - На ru.SO мало интересных вопросов, не на что отвечать

Это проблема скучающих экспертов. Но она имеет и обратную сторону. Интересные вопросы конечно есть, хоть и меньше. Зато на en.SO на них отвечает отряд Джон-Скитов, как будто подключенных к сайту через кабель в затылке, так что дать ответ одновременно быстрее и лучше довольно сложно.

> - SO на русском не нужен

Можно предложить рассказать об этом нескольким десяткам тысяч ежедневных уникальных посетителей.

> - Я не знаю, что есть SO на русском

У сайта очень необычная история, её интересно и рассказывать, и слушать.

> Что бы вы на это возразили? Как можно привлечь русскоязычных программистов и системных администраторов к участию именно в StackOverflow на русском?

Каждый участник сообщества имеет свои сильные стороны: кто-то дает отличные ответы, кто-то наводит порядок, кто-то обучает новичков в боевых условиях. Всё это привлекает новых участников. Лично я вкладываюсь в организацию и улучшение процессов, в обратную связь и развитие сообщества. У меня есть планы по налаживанию связей с местными сибирскими сообществами, но об этом стоит написать отдельный вопрос.

Думаю, по мере роста количества и качества вопросов и ответов сюда будет приходить всё больше отвечающих экспертов и всё больше ищущих решение через поисковики. Хотелось бы, чтобы в будущем в русскоязычной среде оба сайта рассматривались как части единого целого.

---

> Как вы собираетесь действовать в ситуации, когда трактовка одного или нескольких правил (официальных или принятых на Мете) одного из участников или группы участников расходится с вашим пониманием этих же правил?

Есть три разных вещи: реальность, моё понимание правил, моё понимание чьего-то понимания правил. Если есть расхождения между вторым и третьим, проблема может быть где угодно. Я постараюсь уточнить, верно ли я понимаю правила — например, спрошу у других модераторов или в чате. Уточню так же у участника — чем он руководствуется и как понимает те же правила. Думаю, в большинстве случаев будет достаточно связаться с участником и обсудить ситуацию. Если точка зрения высказана на Мете — отлично, я же умею писать длинные ответы на Мете (над короткими я работаю). =)

В редких ситуациях бунта, саботажа и вандализма — смотрите первый вопрос.

---

> Вы получаете большое количество тревог о спорных результатах проверки. Значительная часть их них сгенерирована одним из топовых участников, причем он явно голосует вразрез с решениями на мете. При попытке выяснить причину вы слышите от него "мои голоса, использую их как хочу". Ваши действия?

Ситуации могут быть очень разные:

- Все закрывают вопрос, а один оставляет открытым и сразу редактирует, выясняет подробности, отвечает. Отлично! (Только без курсива в чужом тексте.)
- Один участник закрывает или переоткрывает вопросы, которые явно не стоило закрывать или открывать.

  - Если остальные участники голосуют в рамках правил — ничего страшного, вреда не будет, система не нуждается в помощи или защите. Человек имеет право на своё мнение. Здорово, если начнёт ещё и улучшать сообщения.
  - Если остальные слепо жмут ту же кнопку — тогда есть системная ошибка, нужно доносить до всех этих участников правила, обязательно лично, можно на Мете.
  - Если это организованная группа — смотрите первый вопрос. )

---

Comment: *"Но это искусственная ситуация, я не представляю, что кто-то действительно будет агитировать за плагиат."* — Вы не поверите... =)

Comment: @Discord: ... пока не увижу это своими глазами. =)

Comment: Да вон же, Qwertiy несколько раз отстаивал инфоанархические взгляды в чате, впрочем не слишком яро.

Answer (score 8):

## [Nofate](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/1984/nofate)

> Как вы поступите с участником, который создает большое количество ценных ответов, но порождает массу споров в комментариях, которые впоследствии отмечаются сигналом тревоги?

- Если спор по существу вопроса, то следует отправить спорящих в отдельную чат-комнату. Желательно, чтобы при этом они не забыли вынести результат (если такой появится) в ответ.
- Если это недовольство тревогами/закрытым вопросом, я напоминаю участнику правила сообщества.
- Если это недовольство правилами или отдельными участниками, я всегда предлагаю обсудить это в спокойной обстановке на Мете или в чате.
- Если участник опустился до прямых оскорблений в адрес других или всего сообщества в целом —  ему нужен отдых. Прямо сейчас ничего конструктивного он не привнесет. Есть риск хлопка дверью, но лучше так, чем создавать атмосферу вседозволенности ad honorem.

---

> Как вы поступите в ситуации, когда другой модератор закроет, удалит и т. д. вопрос, который, по вашему мнению, не стоит закрывать, удалять и т. д.?

Необходимо выяснить мотивацию закрывшего, после чего вынести закрытие вопроса на обсуждение. Сперва среди модераторов (для этого есть закрытые чаты), если консенсус не будет достигнут —  с привлечением активной части сообщества в чате или на Мете (в зависимости от серьезности проблемы).

Желательно, чтобы в ходе такой дискуссии были выработаны уточнения к правилам.

---

> Работать на благо сообщества вы можете и без статуса модератора. Так зачем вы действительно решили стать модератором?

Есть вещи, которыми я регулярно занимаюсь, для которых нужен ромб:

- Успокаивание агрессивных пользователей. С одной стороны появление ромба в жаркой дискуссии уже может охладить пыл участников. С другой —  у модератора есть и более радикальные средства, чем вежливые слова.
- В дополнение к предыдущему пункту —  вынесение длинных разговоров из комментариев в чат.
- Перенос/синонимирование меток. Через отдельный инструмент модератора эти процедуры производятся проще и быстрее.
- Уничтожение учетных записей созданных исключительно с хулиганскими целями.
- Выгребание откровенно бесполезных/неуместных постов и комментариев через Data.SO без замусоривания очередей.

---

> Есть ли правила сайта, в том числе принятые сообществом на Мете, с которыми вы не согласны? Если да, то какие, и как вы собираетесь действовать?

На мой взгляд наши правила основаны на здравом смысле и опыте.  Не испытываю с ними проблем.

---

> Есть ли сообщение на Мете (вопрос или ответ), которым вы гордитесь? С какой целью вы его опубликовали и насколько эта цель была достигнута?

Поскольку моя деятельность на Мете большей частью связана с вопросами поддержки участников, то я не вижу смысла выделять какие-то из сообщений. Предметом для гордости мог бы быть очень качественный развернутый пост, вроде некоторых из метки [faq](/questions/tagged/faq). Возможно, мой идеальный мета-пост еще впереди.

---

> Какие основные недостатки и проблемы вы видите в сайте на сегодняшний день? Как они мешают развитию сообщества? Как вы собираетесь с ними бороться?

- Есть много недовольств причинами закрытия. "Вопросы-опросники" убрали из списка, надо работать над ним дальше. Но это не личная ответственность модератора. Тут нужен консенсус сообщества.
- Есть баги локализации UI, есть проблемы локализации справки, есть МНОГО косяков с локализацией модераторской. Тут поможет информирование участников сообщество о том, что каждый может поучаствовать в переводе. Еще было бы здорово иметь кого-то из активных переводчиков (сидящих в Transifex) в команде модераторов.
- Есть участники, которые сидят в очередях проверки (и тем самым влияют на политику сайта), но не появляются в чате и на Мете. Есть люди недовольные правилами, которые считают, что правила SO придуманы неведомыми злыми богами сидящими на Олимпе. И до тех и до других нужно доносить наши ценности и знакомить с возможностями вынести свою точку зрения на обсуждение. К сожалению, они не всегда адекватно реагируют на критику —  тут см. первый вопрос списка.
- Нет окончательного решения, является ли онтопиком "железо" и где граница между тематикой ServerFault и SuperUser.

---

> Проблема была вынесена на Мету, сообщество приняло решение, но вы с ним категорически не согласны. Как вы будете действовать?
>
> <sub>Примеры: разрешать или запрещать вопросы по какой-то тематике, разрешать или запрещать скопированное содержимое без ссылок, удалить или оставить метку и т. п.</sub>

*Dura lex, sed lex*. Пока идет обсуждение —  можно пытаться склонить сообщество к своей точке зрения. Но если решение было принято —  все просто —  нужно следовать.

---

> Достаточно многие русскоязычные специалисты принципиально пользуются StackOverflow на английском (en.SO). Среди них есть как просто ищущие ответы, так и активные участники. Свое предпочтение они аргументируют примерно так (все примеры из личного опыта):
>
> - На en.SO больше ответов и отвечающих, а на ru.SO мало участников, долго дают ответ
> - На ru.SO мало интересных вопросов, не на что отвечать
> - Английский — язык профессионального общения, поэтому нужно спрашивать на нем
> - SO на русском не нужен
> - Я не знаю, что есть SO на русском
>
> Что бы вы на это возразили? Как можно привлечь русскоязычных программистов и системных администраторов к участию именно в StackOverflow на русском?

Прекрасно, что существует англоязычный StackOverflow, большой, активный, быстроотвечающий. Но существует масса людей, которые затрудняются даже сформулировать правильный запрос в гугл на русском языке, не то что выразить суть проблемы на неродном языке. Ведь проблема любого новичка в любом деле — непонимание уровня своего непонимания. Если сюда наложить еще потери информации при переводе сообщений в оба конца, то смысл для спрашивающего может ускользнуть окончательно.  В этом отношении механизм постепенного улучшения вопроса (если, конечно, спрашивающий пойдет навстречу) и диалог на русском языке может изрядно помочь процессу обучения.

Чтобы о RU.SO узнавали, конечно, нужно продвигать его. Но этот вопрос на мой взгляд, лежит больше в компетенции комьюнити-менеджера, нежели модератора. Нужно идти туда, где есть опытные и начинающие программисты/администраторы и рассказывать о нас. DevDays-ы, JUG-и, Codefreez-ы, *-Conf-ы и *-Fest-ы — вот это все.

---

> Как вы собираетесь действовать в ситуации, когда трактовка одного или нескольких правил (официальных или принятых на Мете) одного из участников или группы участников расходится с вашим пониманием этих же правил?

Так же как и с модератором из второго вопроса. Обсудить в комментариях с места событий или в личке → в чате → на Мете. Разобраться в ситуации. В случае разрушительных действий — ограничить пользователя (например, заблокировать правки).

---

> Вы получаете большое количество тревог о спорных результатах проверки. Значительная часть их них сгенерирована одним из топовых участников, причем он явно голосует вразрез с решениями на мете. При попытке выяснить причину вы слышите от него "мои голоса, использую их как хочу". Ваши действия?

Сложно, да и не всегда нужно, заставить участника голосовать так, как нравится большинству. Опять-таки, если его действия не разрушительны, то он может самовыражаться голосами как хочет. Если же прослеживается массовое минусование, вандализм через откат правок, переоткрытие явного оффтопика, иные нарушения правил — нужно разбираться как обычно с нарушениями: на месте — в очевидных ситуациях, при помощи сообщества — в спорных.

Comment: «Еще было бы здорово иметь кого-то из активных переводчиков (сидящих в Transifex) в команде модераторов.» — есть шансы. )

Comment: @NickVolynkin Положим, не шансы, а практически свершившийся факт...

Answer (score 6):

## [PashaPash](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/177221/pashapash)

> Как вы поступите с участником, который создает большое количество ценных ответов, но порождает массу споров в комментариях, которые 
>   впоследствии отмечаются сигналом тревоги?

Зависит от вида споров. Технические споры - обсуждения, указывающие на недостатки конкретного решения - это, в некотором смысле, хорошее 
явление (если они не перерастают во флуд). При перерастании во флуд - просто поспособствую переносу его в чат.

Если же суть спора - агрессия, переход на личности, оскорбление - предупреждение, при повторении - увод участника в readonly.

---

> Как вы поступите в ситуации, когда другой модератор закроет, удалит и т. д. вопрос, который, по вашему мнению, не стоит закрывать, 
>   удалять и т. д.?

Зависит от уровня моего несогласия. Если это был просто спорный вопрос, который я, возможно, оставил бы открытым - просто пройду мимо. У 
другого модератора наверняка были причины для закрытия/удаления - он же не случайный человек, который модерирует по желанию левой пятки - 
ведь мы именно сейчас и занимаемся тем, что выбираем этого неслучайного человека :)

Если же я в корне несогласен с его решением - свяжусь с ним в личке обсужу ситуацию.

Чего я точно делать не буду - не буду молча отменять его решение.

---

> Работать на благо сообщества вы можете и без статуса модератора. Так зачем вы действительно решили стать модератором?

В первую очередь - для того, чтобы направить рвение остальных пользователей, которые стараются улучшить сайт, в общее русло.

Невозможность хоть как-то подтолкнуть активных участников из очередей проверок к общению на мете - очень сильно мешает. Отсутствие 
возможности видеть спорные результаты проверок - мешает еще больше. Я могу искать спорные ситуации и без статуса модератора, но нехватка инструментов делает этот процесс жутко неэффективным. Так что я решил стать модератором ради инструментов, а совсем не ради возможности 
закрыть все в один клик :)

---

> Есть ли правила сайта, в том числе принятые сообществом на Мете, с которыми вы не согласны? Если да, то какие, и как вы собираетесь 
>   действовать?

Решений, с которым я полностью несогласен - нет. Есть решения, которые вызывают у меня сомнения в их эффективности или целесообразности - например, решение относительно [общих вопросов про книги](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/162/177221), или попытки активно синонимизировать некоторые метки (без накопления статистики по использованию) - но их можно проверить только временем, так что пока я стараюсь поддерживать их, и смотреть на результаты.

---

> Есть ли сообщение на Мете (вопрос или ответ), которым вы гордитесь? С какой целью вы его опубликовали и насколько эта цель была достигнута?

[Проблемы причины закрытия "опросник" и возможные решения](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1918/)
- я все-таки довел администрацию в лице Николаса до удаления причины закрытия "Опросник", с которой закрывалась половина вопросов на сайте. Не могу сказать что это повод для гордости, но это самое времязатратное решение на сайте (несколько месяцев нытья!), с которым мне пришлось столкнуться.

---

> Какие основные недостатки и проблемы вы видите в сайте на сегодняшний день? Как они мешают развитию сообщества? Как вы собираетесь с ними бороться?

Основная проблема - закрытие и удаление вопросов, вместо их улучшения. Ее частные проявления:

- Агрессия в направлении новичков. Это снижает поток вопросов, делает сайт менее интересным для постоянных участников, и в целом ведет к застою и упадку.
- Закрытие вопросов ради закрытия. Закрытие - "требование правки" - должно использоваться в случаях, когда вопрос нужно исправить, и сделать этот может только сам автор вопроса.
- Закрытие вразрез решениям на мете. Даже общие вопросы по книгам особо рьяные участники успевали закрывать, не говоря уже о решениях "на грани" вроде [работы за автора](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/231/).

Как бороться? В меру сил доносить решения до участников, проверяющих очереди. Призывать их к общению на мете. Направлять в более конструктивное русло - предлагать править и комментировать, а не просто закрывать.

---

> Проблема была вынесена на Мету, сообщество приняло решение, но вы с ним категорически не согласны. Как вы будете действовать?
>
> <sub>Примеры: разрешать или запрещать вопросы по какой-то тематике, разрешать или запрещать скопированное содержимое без ссылок, удалить 
>   или оставить метку и т. п.</sub>

Если решение требует активного вмешательства модератора - поддержу его по мере сил.

Если же решение вмешательства не требует модератора (т.е. возможности модератора ничем не помогут - например, сжигание какой-то метки, которую лично я не считаю проблемной, но которую хотят сжечь остальные участники) - оставлю его исполнение на усмотрение остальных участников. Их больше, и многие вещи несколько обычных участников могут делать гораздо эффективнее одного модератора - от наличия ромба скорость печати не повышается :)

---

> Достаточно многие русскоязычные специалисты принципиально пользуются StackOverflow на английском (en.SO). Среди них есть как просто 
>   ищущие ответы, так и активные участники. Свое предпочтение они аргументируют примерно так (все примеры из личного опыта):
>
> - На en.SO больше ответов и отвечающих, а на ru.SO мало участников, долго дают ответ
> - На ru.SO мало интересных вопросов, не на что отвечать
> - Английский — язык профессионального общения, поэтому нужно спрашивать на нем
> - SO на русском не нужен
> - Я не знаю, что есть SO на русском
>
> Что бы вы на это возразили? Как можно привлечь русскоязычных программистов и системных администраторов к участию именно в StackOverflow 
>   на русском?

Для последнего пункта - "Я не знаю, что есть SO на русском" - естественный ответ "теперь знаешь!".

Для остальных - во первых, насильно мил не будешь. Если человеку удобнее формулировать вопросы и отвечеть на англиском - это его право.

Важно понимать, что вопросы и ответы пишутся не для спрашивающих и не для отвечающих. 99% посещений сайта - это анонимные пользователи из поисковика. Им все равно, на enSO, ruSO или ответы.мейлру привел их поисковик (ну ок, возможно ответы.мейлру в этом списке лишние). Если они нашли решение - они счастливы и у вас улучшилась карма (вне зависимости, написали ли вы в этом вопросе огромный ответ, или просто код отформатировали).

Лично я несколько раз уже приходил из поисковика на свои собственные ответы, решение из которых я просто забыл. После этого аргументы "ru.SO не нужен" перестали на меня действовать.

---

> Как вы собираетесь действовать в ситуации, когда трактовка одного или нескольких правил (официальных или принятых на Мете) одного из 
>   участников или группы участников расходится с вашим пониманием этих же правил?

Вынесу на обсуждение на мете. Если на основе неоднозначного правила предпринимаются активные действия - попрошу их притормозить до получения отклика от остальных участников.

---

> Вы получаете большое количество тревог о спорных результатах проверки. Значительная часть их них сгенерирована одним из топовых 
>   участников, причем он явно голосует вразрез с решениями на мете. При попытке выяснить причину вы слышите от него "мои голоса, использую их 
>   как хочу". Ваши действия?

Голос действительно полностью принадлежит пользователю. Но голосование вразрез решениям на мете приводит к достаточно очевидному результату - принявших решение на мете обычно просто больше. И они легко перевесят голос одного упрямого участника. Да и система аудита проверок более-менее отсеивает голоса "как хочу".

Проблемы начинаются когда те, кто на мету не заходит, начинают подхватывать решение этого участника в очереди проверок - например, голосовать за закрытие вопроса только потому, что кто-то уже за него проголосовал, с той же (противоречащей решению на мете) причиной. Тогда это ведет или к войне правок (открывашки vs закрывашки), или к выбрасыванию плохих сообщений из очереди (в очереди низкого качества достаточно двух голосов "выглядит нормально", чтобы прекратить проверку.

Последнее особенно заметно при расстановке тревог на старых вопросах-ссылках - примерно 20% тревог помечаются как спорные, причем даже те, где ссылка ведет в 404. И те, где ссылка ведет в гугл, который ведет обратно на этот же вопрос.

Это тот случай, когда "я так хочу" приводит к ухудшению контента. Умышленная порча контента - это прямой аналог вандализма - и повод для принятия сдерживающих мер.

Comment: Вот интересно, минус-то за что?

Answer (score 4):

## [Qwertiy](//ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178988/qwertiy)

> Как вы поступите с участником, который создает большое количество ценных ответов, но порождает массу споров в комментариях, которые впоследствии отмечаются сигналом тревоги?

Зависит от характера споров.

Если его комментарии представляют ценность и в них он указывает на какие-либо моменты, относящиеся к вопросу или ответу, то ничего не сделаю и отклоню тревоги. Собственно, он заслужил свой рейтинг, ясно что он является хорошим специалистом, так что он полностью заслужил своё право критиковать ответы.

Если он постоянно и без повода разводит демагогию, попрошу его использовать для этого чат, а не комментарии к вопросу. Соответственно, комментарии перенесу в чат.

Если он проявляет агрессию, необоснованно нападает на других участников, то тут уже надо будет детально разбираться, что происходит. Подобное поведение от заслуженного участника, хорошо представляющего правила, кажется мне весьма маловероятным. В случае крайней необходимости, придётся прибегнуть к временному бану.

---

> Как вы поступите в ситуации, когда другой модератор закроет, удалит и т. д. вопрос, который, по вашему мнению, не стоит закрывать, удалять и т. д.?

К сожалению, сейчас многие действия модераторов могут быть отменены только действиями других модераторов. Например, на удалённых вопросах нельзя проголосовать за восстановление, можно только поставить тревогу модератору. Это было небольшое отступление.

Во-первых, я постараюсь узнать у того модератора, почему он так поступил.

Затем, если речь идёт об обратимом обычными пользователями действии, кину вопрос в [один из чатов](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1839/178988) на рассмотрение обычным пользователям.

Если разногласия не вызваны правилами сайта и действие может обратить только модератор, то можно на мете устроить голосование. Вообще, мне кажется хорошей идеей создать на мете тему, где в качестве ответов пользователи смогут просить восстановить незаслуженно удалённые вопросы и голосовать за это. Т. е. фактически дать пользователям возможность принимать решение, переопределяющее мнение модератора. Естественно, предполагается, что кто-то потом это решение применит.

Если разногласия по вопросу вызваны различной трактовкой правил сайта, например, тематики, и эти правила ещё не обсуждались, то идти не по пути выше (с восстановлением конкретного вопроса), а создать на мете обсуждение данного момента правил в целом, с вопросом в качестве примера.

---

> Работать на благо сообщества вы можете и без статуса модератора. Так зачем вы действительно решили стать модератором?

Это расширит мои возможности и позволит видеть более полную картину.

---

> Есть ли правила сайта, в том числе принятые сообществом на Мете, с которыми вы не согласны? Если да, то какие, и как вы собираетесь действовать?

Пожалуй только ограничение тематики. Вполне очевидно, кто здесь преимущественно находится, на какие вопросы они могут ответить и что из этого может представлять пользу. Я считаю строгое следование тематике неправильным подходом, пригодным только для вопросов среднего качества. Низкокачественные вопросы должны закрываться независимо от соответствия тематике (впрочем, с этим проблем нет), а хорошие околотематические оставаться. Т. е. я ставлю интересность и полезность вопроса, на который тут могут ответить, выше, чем формальные правила о тематике. Я даже создал [чат для переоткрытия вопросов](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32012/) с этой целью. К сожалению, после выхода из беты там сложно что-то сделать...

---

> Есть ли сообщение на Мете (вопрос или ответ), которым вы гордитесь? С какой целью вы его опубликовали и насколько эта цель была достигнута?

Хм.. Достаточно сложно ответить на этот вопрос.

С другой стороны, пока я отвечал на предыдущие вопросы, я дважды упомянул чат для переоткрытия вопросов. Так что весьма вероятно, что его и стоит тут назвать.

Что касается достигнутости цели, то частично она достигнута - некоторые вопросы были переоткрыты услилиями участников чата. С другой стороны, были переоткрыты даже не все вопросы из тех, ради которых этот чат создавался. Выводы делайте сами :)

---

> Какие основные недостатки и проблемы вы видите в сайте на сегодняшний день? Как они мешают развитию сообщества? Как вы собираетесь с ними бороться?

Пользователи не следуют решениям, принятым на мете.
Постараюсь связаться с пользователем и сказать, в чём он не прав.

Новички задают низкокачественные вопросы.
В зависимости от адекватности вопросов, стараться их улучшить и помочь пользователю освоиться, или закрывать, написав, что именно он сделал не так.

Закрытие или удаление вопросов среднего качества, когда наличие ответа может спасти вопрос.
Существует Дух сообщества, который удалит неинтересные вопросы без ответов. Я считаю, что на эту возможность и следует полагаться, а не стараться агрессивно закрывать и удалять такие вопросы. Либо вопрос спасётся благодаря хорошему ответу, либо исчезнет сам. Но единолично переоткрывать такие вопросы я не буду - только на усмотрение сообщества - привет чат :)

---

> Проблема была вынесена на Мету, сообщество приняло решение, но вы с ним категорически не согласны. Как вы будете действовать?
>
> <sub>Примеры: разрешать или запрещать вопросы по какой-то тематике, разрешать или запрещать скопированное содержимое без ссылок, удалить или оставить метку и т. п.</sub>

По концептуальным правилам - буду следовать им. Если есть особые случаи, которые должны быть исключениями, подниму уточняющий вопрос на мете.

По тематике - я уже сказал, что считаю ценность вопросов приоритетнее следования тематике, так что в этом плане я в некоторых случаях буду игнорировать лимиты определённой на мете тематики.

Что касается скопированного содержимого. Я нейтрально отношусь к этому правилу, но следование ему просто не проверяю. Я слежу за адекватностью, но не ищу источник. В любом случае, это не дожно вызывать проблем, поскольку скопированную информацию можно удалить уже по факту.

---

> Достаточно многие русскоязычные специалисты принципиально пользуются StackOverflow на английском (en.SO). Среди них есть как просто ищущие ответы, так и активные участники. Свое предпочтение они аргументируют примерно так (все примеры из личного опыта):
>
> - На en.SO больше ответов и отвечающих, а на ru.SO мало участников, долго дают ответ
> - На ru.SO мало интересных вопросов, не на что отвечать
> - Английский — язык профессионального общения, поэтому нужно спрашивать на нем
> - SO на русском не нужен
> - Я не знаю, что есть SO на русском
>
> Что бы вы на это возразили? Как можно привлечь русскоязычных программистов и системных администраторов к участию именно в StackOverflow на русском?

Перед тем как задать вопрос на enSO я задаю вопрос на ruSO. Вопрос на английском появляется только если тут мне не отвечают, либо я хочу сразу охватить б**о**льшую аудиторию. Оба вопроса связаны ссылками, ответ с одного ресурса я указываю и на другом. [Свежий пример.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/476703/178988).

Если здесь будет достаточно хорошего контента и хорошие вопросы, то пользователи-эксперты сами придут. Кроме того, мы же фактически учим здешних пользователей - мы вполне можем вырастить экспертов и тут.

---

> Как вы собираетесь действовать в ситуации, когда трактовка одного или нескольких правил (официальных или принятых на Мете) одного из участников или группы участников расходится с вашим пониманием этих же правил?

Постараюсь обсудить этот вопрос с ним. Затем, задам вопрос на мете, чтобы всё сообщество приняло участие в обсуждении.

---

> Вы получаете большое количество тревог о спорных результатах проверки. Значительная часть их них сгенерирована одним из топовых участников, причем он явно голосует вразрез с решениями на мете. При попытке выяснить причину вы слышите от него "мои голоса, использую их как хочу". Ваши действия?

Он это право заслужил. Вероятно, некоторые правила можно обсудить на мете ещё раз, добавив его доводы по этим вопросам.

---

> Что, по вашему, должно быть не первом месте? Дисциплина либо количество пользоватлей?

Ни то, ни другое.

Правила применимы для средних случаев, для обоих крайних ситуация меняется. Я принципиально против упихивания сайта в строгие рамки. Но и гнаться за количеством пользователей и вопросов неверно. Важна ценность пользователей и вопросов для сообщества.

---

> Как модератор, вы больше не сможете выносить закрытие вопроса на рассмотрение другими участниками. Вы сможете или сразу закрыть, или молча пройти мимо. Считаете ли вы, что решение о закрытии вопросов должно приниматься в первую очередь сообществом, и модератор должен лишь направлять и поддерживать его? Или вы будете просто закрывать вопросы в одиночку?

[Есть чаты](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1839/178988). Теперь уже их два - один создан мной для переоткрытия вопросов, другой - для закрытия - был отдан Discord'у. Я по-прежнему смогу скидывать сомнительные вопросы в эти чаты, отдавая право принимать решение сообществу.

Я не буду единолично принимать решение в пограничных случаях, а также в случаях, когда не уверен в своей правоте. У меня сейчас 71 тревога, из которых 70 полезных и 1 спорная. Я не стремлюсь чистить всё и вся.

---

> Просматривая историю своих проверок, вы обнаруживаете, что ваше мнение очень часто расходится с мнением большинства. Ваши действия?

Модератором я буду аккуратнее относиться к голосованиям, оставляя пограничные ситуации на рассмотрение сообщества. На мой взгляд, это правильно. А сейчас есть замечательная возможность выступать в роли одного из голосующих.

---

Спасибо всем, кто дочитал до конца :)

Comment: Спасибо за три бонусных ответа. :)) *"Вообще, мне кажется хорошей идеей создать на мете тему"* — В инструментах модератора есть список недавно удалённых вопросов, свежие голоса за восстановление там же. Туда сыпется автоматически собранный мусор, к сожалению, но в целом инструмент слежения за удалениями и влияния на это уже есть, и он вам доступен. *"я дважды упомянул чат для переоткрытия вопросов"* — Вообще-то речь про Мету шла, а не про чат.

Comment: _В инструментах модератора есть список недавно удалённых вопросов, свежие голоса за восстановление там же_ - попробуй проголосовать за восстановление любого сообщения, удалённого модератором - система не позволит, так что голосов за восстановление в этом случае вообще быть не может. Только тревога модератору, с которой неясно что делать. Я же предлагаю естественное голосование. _Вообще-то речь про Мету шла, а не про чат._ - на мете есть объявление об этом чате. И по сути вопроса он подходит. К тому же, не каждый пользователь может сказать что-то подобное.

Comment: @Discord, забыл позвать, а править поздно)

Comment: "*Я же предлагаю естественное голосование.*" — Вы бы как-нибудь в виде поста оформили идею. Пока идея мне видится сомнительной.

Comment: Слишком часто у вас проскакивает мысль "_А давайте вместо очередей на закрытие и переоткрытие вопросов будем использовать чаты..._" Зачем дублировать функционал системы? Или формальные правила и инструменты сообщества - для слабаков?

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, это не дублирование функционала. Есть критерии, по которым вопросы попадают в очередь проверки. И, если не ошибаюсь, отредактированные после длительной паузы никуда не попадают. Идея чатов в обработке того, что в очереди либо не попадает, либо что требуется обсудить.

Answer (score 3):

[**alexander barakin**](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/178576)

> Как вы поступите с участником, который создает большое количество ценных ответов, но порождает массу споров в комментариях, которые впоследствии отмечаются сигналом тревоги?

неконструктивные/оскорбительные комментарии, конечно, подлежат удалению.
если тот, кто *регулярно* оставляет такие комментарии, не поддаётся многократному «доброму слову», то модератор будет вынужден применить «пистолет»: *временный* запрет (если это позволяет движок) оставлять комментарии или (если не позволяет) любые сообщения.

---

> Как вы поступите в ситуации, когда другой модератор закроет, удалит и т. д. вопрос, который, по вашему мнению, не стоит закрывать, удалять и т. д.?

спрошу у коллеги — чем он руководствовался, изложу, почему я считаю иначе. вполне возможно, что он и (или) я просто не обладаем всей информацией.

---

> Работать на благо сообщества вы можете и без статуса модератора. Так зачем вы действительно решили стать модератором?

наводить порядок — это скучная выматывающая рутина. заниматься этим долгое время получается далеко не у всех. я считаю, что у меня это выходит не так уж и плохо: взгляните на статистику проверок в любой из очередей.

---

> Есть ли правила сайта, в том числе принятые сообществом на Мете, с которыми вы не согласны? Если да, то какие, и как вы собираетесь действовать?

мне не известно ни одно правило, противоречащее здравому смыслу, потому и «несоглашаться» не с чем.

---

> Есть ли сообщение на Мете (вопрос или ответ), которым вы гордитесь? С какой целью вы его опубликовали и насколько эта цель была достигнута?

[Предлагается переоткрытие мною же исправленного вопроса](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1429/178576)
хотел устранить возникающую несправедливость — «дополнительный» голос за переоткрытие у внёсшего правку в закрытый вопрос, но, увы, это, видимо, неустранимый баг движка.

---

> Какие основные недостатки и проблемы вы видите в сайте на сегодняшний день? Как они мешают развитию сообщества? Как вы собираетесь с ними бороться?

я считаю, что подобной «политикой» модератор вообще не должен заниматься. разве что в «свободное от работы время».

---

> Проблема была вынесена на Мету, сообщество приняло решение, но вы с ним категорически не согласны. Как вы будете действовать?
>
> <sub>Примеры: разрешать или запрещать вопросы по какой-то тематике, разрешать или запрещать скопированное содержимое без ссылок, удалить или оставить метку и т. п.</sub>

если принятое большинством голосующих решение потребует от меня обязательного совершения абсурдных или аморальных (с моей точки зрения) действий, я сложу с себя полномочия модератора. во всех иных случаях буду подчиняться воле большинства.

---

> Достаточно многие русскоязычные специалисты принципиально пользуются StackOverflow на английском (en.SO). Среди них есть как просто ищущие ответы, так и активные участники. Свое предпочтение они аргументируют примерно так (все примеры из личного опыта):
>
> - На en.SO больше ответов и отвечающих, а на ru.SO мало участников, долго дают ответ
> - На ru.SO мало интересных вопросов, не на что отвечать
> - Английский — язык профессионального общения, поэтому нужно спрашивать на нем
> - SO на русском не нужен
> - Я не знаю, что есть SO на русском
>
> Что бы вы на это возразили? Как можно привлечь русскоязычных программистов и системных администраторов к участию именно в StackOverflow на русском?

ответ такой же, как и на один из вопросов выше:
я считаю, что подобной «политикой» модератор вообще не должен заниматься. разве что в «свободное от работы время».

---

> Как вы собираетесь действовать в ситуации, когда трактовка одного или нескольких правил (официальных или принятых на Мете) одного из участников или группы участников расходится с вашим пониманием этих же правил?

задам на «мете» вопрос по поводу толкования этой неоднозначной трактовки.

---

> Вы получаете большое количество тревог о спорных результатах проверки. Значительная часть их них сгенерирована одним из топовых участников, причем он явно голосует вразрез с решениями на мете. При попытке выяснить причину вы слышите от него "мои голоса, использую их как хочу". Ваши действия?

во-первых, если не помогают увещевания действовать так, как решило большинсто, то попробую убедить его не голосовать вообще, во-вторых, проверки — это коллективная работа, поэтому один «идущий не в ногу» вряд ли сможет причинить сайту ощутимый вред, а вскоре движок может и заблокировать возможность голосований этому пользователю, если он несколько раз «срежется» на контрольных голосованиях.

Answer (score 2):

### [**Suvitruf**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/15479/suvitruf)

> Как вы поступите с участником, который создает большое количество
>   ценных ответов, но порождает массу споров в комментариях, которые
>   впоследствии отмечаются сигналом тревоги?

От специфики тревоги зависит. Из тех, что сейчас доступны при отправке тревоги, самая, хм, нехорошая - тревога о "нецензурном или оскорбительном" комментарии. Сами комментарии, естественно, будут удалятся. Дальше будет вестись беседа с участниками. Если будут рецидивы, то, предполагаю, временная блокировка аккаунта.

> Как вы поступите в ситуации, когда другой модератор закроет, удалит и
>   т. д. вопрос, который, по вашему мнению, не стоит закрывать, удалять и
>   т. д.?

Обсуждение ситуации с модератором. Если же не сможем прийти к консенсусу, то обсудим в глобальном чате. Если не будет однозначной оценки ситуации со стороны остальных членов сообщества, то поднимем вопрос на мете, чтобы уже сообщество решило.

> Работать на благо сообщества вы можете и без статуса модератора. Так
>   зачем вы действительно решили стать модератором?

Некоторые вещи сложно делать при текущих ограничениях. Это касается и закрытия вопросов, и работу со старыми вопросами. Очень много старых вопросов до сих пор нуждаются в правках. Многих из таких вопросов следует закрыть, так как решение уже найдено, или же они не явно не соответствуют тематике текущего SO. С инструментами модератора этот процесс был бы куда проще и быстрее. Плюс будут доп. инструменты для работы с метками, а то на данный момент ситуация с ними очень плачевная.

Если же резюмировать всё это, то я хочу стать модератором, чтоб принести ещё больше пользы сообществу.

> Есть ли правила сайта, в том числе принятые сообществом на Мете, с
>   которыми вы не согласны? Если да, то какие, и как вы собираетесь
>   действовать?

С глобальными правила в целом проблем нет. С некоторыми решениями на мете не совсем согласен. Например [решение о faq метках](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/693/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BC-%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC-c-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-faq). Последние дни ярый спор в чатике был по поводу этого - нужны такие метки или нет.

Суть не в конкретных прениях, а в том, что независимо от собственного мнения, модератор должен следовать воле сообщества. Так что, отвечая на вопрос о том "как я собираюсь действовать", скажу, что попробую перед сообществом отстоять свою точку зрения. Если же не выйдет, то выполнять решения принятые на мете, даже если они расходятся с моим личным мнением.

> Есть ли сообщение на Мете (вопрос или ответ), которым вы гордитесь? С
>   какой целью вы его опубликовали и насколько эта цель была достигнута?

Возможно [ответ на вопрос "В чем интерес быть модератором"](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2065/%D0%92-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81-%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC/2068#2068). Опубликовал, чтоб донести мысль о том, для многе время, проведённое на SO, не считают "потраченным". Или же [ответ об устройстве сообщества](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1860/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE-stack-overflow-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC/1861#1861). Из вопросов - вопрос о том, [на кого рассчитывать ответ?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1872/%D0%9D%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82) Так сказать, вопрос о том, с чем мы сталкиваемся каждый день.

> Какие основные недостатки и проблемы вы видите в сайте на сегодняшний
>   день? Как они мешают развитию сообщества? Как вы собираетесь с ними
>   бороться?

Многие проблемы вытекают из того, что раньше на hashcode политика и правила были другими, плюс последствия переезда. Из конкретных проблем я вижу:

1. **Проблема новичков**. Новички не читают правила, в следствии чего их первые вопросы часто закрываются по причинам: "необходимо конкретизировать вопрос" и т.п. Это отпугивает новичков. Плюс проблема ещё в самих правилах. У нас очень много обсуждений на мете, решения по которым даже с правилами не состыкуются. Новички о них могут никогда и не узнать вовсе. Сюда же можно отнести проблему, что текущие активные юзеры игнорируют мету.
2. **Закрытые вопрос**. Необходимо до всех донести, что для начала лучше попытаться улучшить вопрос, прежде чем его закрывать. Я и сам порой грешил тем, что голосовал за закрытие, хотя, по-хорошему, надо сначала попросить автора вопроса привести оный к подобающему виду. Буду доносить эту мысль и до других.
3. **Бесполезные/вредные метки**. Сейчас вычищаю, к примеру, тег [ошибки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8). Но таких меток уйма, и все необходимо подчистить.

> Проблема была вынесена на Мету, сообщество приняло решение, но вы с ним категорически не согласны. Как вы будете действовать?
>
> <sub>Примеры: разрешать или запрещать вопросы по какой-то тематике, разрешать или запрещать скопированное содержимое без ссылок, удалить или оставить метку и т. п.</sub>

Всё это необходимо обсуждать. В конечном итоге решение всегда за сообществом. Модератор не может единолично принимать решения. Его голос может быть решающим в споре, да. Но если его мнение кардинально расходится с решением по какому-то вопросу на мете, он должен выполнять эти решения, независимо от своего мнения.

> Достаточно многие русскоязычные специалисты принципиально пользуются StackOverflow на английском (en.SO). Среди них есть как просто ищущие ответы, так и активные участники. Свое предпочтение они аргументируют примерно так (все примеры из личного опыта):
>
> - На en.SO больше ответов и отвечающих, а на ru.SO мало участников, долго дают ответ
> - На ru.SO мало интересных вопросов, не на что отвечать
>     Английский — язык профессионального общения, поэтому нужно спрашивать на нем
> - SO на русском не нужен
> - Я не знаю, что есть SO на русском
>
> Что бы вы на это возразили? Как можно привлечь русскоязычных программистов и системных администраторов к участию именно в StackOverflow на русском?

А тут сложно возразить, так как частично они правы.

Вопросы я хожу задавать на en StackOverflow, как минимум потому что там больше людей, больше шанс получить ответ. Во-вторых, вопросы у меня как правило специфические, по конкретной технологии/библиотеке. И очень часто авторы этих библиотек сами отвечают на вопрос. Например, автор netty постоянно помогает людям по вопросам, связанным с библиотекой. Jake Wharton постоянно помогает в ответах (кто работает с Android, должны быть в курсе, кто это).

Сам на ru StackOverflow сижу именно, чтоб отвечать. И мне приятно, что мой опыт позволит другим сэкономить время, научиться новому, поможет решить проблему. Привлекать? В иностранных компаниях люди часто в CV указывают ссылка на свой профиль на SO, для иностранных компаний это имеет немалое значение. Точно так же как ваш профиль на github. Думаю, если продвигать эту идею и у нас, тогда специалисты начнут указывать в своих резюме ссылку на свой профиль на ru StackOverflow. Надо как-то дать понять компаниям понять, что активность на ru StackOverflow - это большой плюс к кандидату.

> Вы получаете большое количество тревог о спорных результатах проверки.
>   Значительная часть их них сгенерирована одним из топовых участников,
>   причем он явно голосует вразрез с решениями на мете. При попытке
>   выяснить причину вы слышите от него "мои голоса, использую их как
>   хочу". Ваши действия?

Я, конечно, не могу запретить ему использовать голоса как он хочет, но хотя бы попробую донести мысль, что у нас всё-таки **сообщество**.

Вопросы, не вошедшие в топ:

Вопрос от @PashaPash

> Как модератор, вы больше не сможете выносить закрытие вопроса на
>   рассмотрение другими участниками. Вы сможете или сразу закрыть, или
>   молча пройти мимо. Считаете ли вы, что решение о закрытии вопросов
>   должно приниматься в первую очередь сообществом, и модератор должен
>   лишь направлять и поддерживать его? Или вы будете просто закрывать
>   вопросы в одиночку?

Буду сразу закрывать вопросы, которые не вызывают разночтений. Если же есть хоть небольшое подозрение, что этот вопрос должен жить, то уточню в чате, что думают люди по этому поводу. В крайнем случае вопрос на мете задам.

Вопрос от @Vlad

> Что вы предлагаете делать с новичками, которые задают вопросы по
>   учебным заданиям? Есть ли стратегия лучше, чем просто закрывать
>   вопросы?

Если вопрос из разряда "ничего сам не делал, помогите", то, вероятно, закрывать. Если есть хоть малейшая возможность вытянуть вопрос и поправить, то можно и оставить.

Comment: К ответу на «Какие основные недостатки и проблемы вы видите в сайте на сегодняшний день? Как они мешают развитию сообщества? Как вы собираетесь с ними бороться?» — а как вы собираетесь бороться с Проблемой Новичков?

Comment: @VladD "бороться" не совсем уместно. Скорее, помогать новичкам. Плюс, всё же, донести до нынешних активных юзеров, что прежде чем закрыть вопрос, лучше попросить автора улучшить его. Бóльшая проблема в том, как донести до них правила и решения на мете. Как решить эту проблему пока не могу однозначно ответить. Были обсуждение и в чате, и на мете, но к нормальному результату не пришли пока.

Comment: @NickVolynkin во все ответы настолько вчитываетесь? )

Comment: @Suvitruf я ж граммар-наци, у меня на ошибки Exception выскакивает. :)

Comment: @NickVolynkin Я тоже прерии заметил, но с трудом всё-таки поборол желание исправлять речь другого кандидата. %) Меня ещё сильно напрягает, что заголовки оформлены по-разному, и у некоторых кандидатов список в одном из вопросов оформлен неверно (наверное, скопировали до того, как я исправил оформление в вопросе).

Comment: @Discord узнаю брата-главреда. :)

Answer (score -1):

[**Risto**](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/14756/risto)

> Как вы поступите с участником, который создает большое количество
>   ценных ответов, но порождает массу споров в комментариях, которые
>   впоследствии отмечаются сигналом тревоги?

Буду подавлять конфликты, не трогая участника, так как его уход навредит сообществу больше, чем дурной характер.

---

> Как вы поступите в ситуации, когда другой модератор закроет, удалит и
>   т. д. вопрос, который, по вашему мнению, не стоит закрывать, удалять и
>   т. д.?

Вынесу спор на всеобщее обсуждение, чтобы выработать позицию по данному инциденту и всем подобным. Если позиция была выработана, но проигнорирована модератором - восстановню/открою вопрос и пожалуюсь вышестояшему модератору, если только данное решение не было принято с его санкции.

---

> Работать на благо сообщества вы можете и без статуса модератора. Так
>   зачем вы действительно решили стать модератором?

Потому что лучше хотя бы **попробовать** стать модератором самому, чем сидеть и ныть "модератор N меня не устраивает".

---

> Есть ли правила сайта, в том числе принятые сообществом на Мете, с
>   которыми вы не согласны? Если да, то какие, и как вы собираетесь
>   действовать?

Меня многое раздражает, но это вопрос не правил, а мироощущения отдельных членов сообщества. Его, в отличии от правил, могут изменить только они сами, а потому ничего предпринимать на этот счёт я не намерен.

---

> Есть ли сообщение на Мете (вопрос или ответ), которым вы гордитесь? С
>   какой целью вы его опубликовали и насколько эта цель была достигнута?

У меня всего одно сообщение на Мете, это - второе) Но, в любом случае, гордиться сообщением на Мете, это как гордиться речью на площади. Такие вещи делают ради результата, а не раздувания ЧСВ. Если речью можно гордиться, то, в первую очередь, ей будут гордиться слушатели, а не оратор.

---

> Какие основные недостатки и проблемы вы видите в сайте на сегодняшний
>   день? Как они мешают развитию сообщества? Как вы собираетесь с ними
>   бороться?

- Бардак в метках. Лечится штатными средствами, плюс переговорами с сообществом. Не мешает, но и не помогает, а от ненужного надо избавляться.
- Перекос интересов сообщества в сторону модерирования, как самоцели, в ущерб работе с вопросами. Чем мешает - очевидно. Лечится мониторингом ленты с бомбардировкой чата ссылками на новые вопросы. Возможно - раздачей конкурсов (посмотрю, как с репутацией будет). Модерированием, чтоб другим модерки не оставалось.
- Отсутствие ясного понимания формата сайта у сообщества, и переоценённые ожидания от проекта у некоторых участников. Лечится совместной работой над проектом, но ей же и препятствует. Для выхода из замкнутого круга стоит приучать участников проводить обсуждения на Мете, а не в чате. Такой формат даёт больше времени обдумать слова собеседника и свой ответ, позволяет большему числу участников присоединиться к обсуждению и снижает накал страстей. В чате же стоит обсуждать только рабочие моменты.

---

> Достаточно многие русскоязычные специалисты принципиально пользуются
>   StackOverflow на английском (en.SO). Среди них есть как просто ищущие
>   ответы, так и активные участники. Свое предпочтение они аргументируют
>   примерно так (все примеры из личного опыта):
>
> ...
>
> Что бы вы на это возразили? Как можно привлечь русскоязычных
>   программистов и системных администраторов к участию именно в
>   StackOverflow на русском?

Неправильная постановка задачи. Наш ресурс действительно слабее англоязычно, и убедить кого-то в обратном сможет только гипнотизёр со стажем. Но тут есть маленькая тонкость: Эксперты, специализирующиеся на ответах на вопросы, часто получают удовольствие от самого процесса, а вот в вопросах у нас недостатка нет. Сначала надо привлекать их, а уже затем, повысив качество и количество ответов, остальную аудиторию.

---

> Как вы собираетесь действовать в ситуации, когда трактовка одного или
>   нескольких правил (официальных или принятых на Мете) одного из
>   участников или группы участников расходится с вашим пониманием этих же
>   правил?

Обсужу конфликт другими модераторами, как выбранными представителями сообщества, и выработаю с ними общую точку зрения по данному вопросу, согласно которой и буду действовать.

---

> Вы получаете большое количество тревог о спорных результатах проверки.
>   Значительная часть их них сгенерирована одним из топовых участников,
>   причем он явно голосует вразрез с решениями на мете. При попытке
>   выяснить причину вы слышите от него "мои голоса, использую их как
>   хочу". Ваши действия?

Как ни странно, пользователь прав, - это действительно его голос и он в праве голосовать так, как сам считает нужным. Моральный же аспект его поведения - вне юрисдикции модератора. Однако, окончательное решение по спорным вопросам всё равно будет принято в пользу решений на Мете.

Comment: "Буду подавлять конфликты, не трогая участника" - не трогая участника конфликта? Он тогда и дальше будет продолжать порождать конфликты.

Comment: @Suvitruf будет, конечно. Но для того и нужен модератор, чтобы конфликты не выходили за рамки, а жать на кнопочку "бан" и специально обученная котейка может. С другой стороны, он будет порождать и качественный контент, с отсутствием которого вряд ли можно справиться хоть какой модерацией.

Comment: Это как страус, который закапывает голову в песок. С нарушителями необходимо вести беседу, как мне кажется.

Comment: @Suvitruf вести беседы - да, банить - нет. Не в опмисанном случае.