# Блокировка ценного участника сайта

Tags: обсуждение, блокировка

В одном из вопросов наткнулся на ответ от опытного участника и удивился, что рейтинг у него стал равен 1, хотя был, по-моему, выше 10к.

Увидел блокировку на **3 месяца**. Собственно, вопрос - а стоит ли так долго блокировать пользователей, которые дали более **1000** ответов и помогли многим участникам этого сайта? И за что такая крупная блокировка? Как минимум, после такого вряд ли появится желание отвечать на вопросы у этого пользователя, что не есть хорошо для ресурса.

Comment: собственно срок за рецидив.

Comment: @Grundy на 3 месяца? мне кажется, польза сообществу гораздо весомей, чем некорректное поведение в комментариях. P.S. с юзером не знаком, не защищаю, но осуждаю такую долгую блокировку в ущерб пользы от его хороших ответов.

Comment: А стоит ли ценному участнику научиться себя культурно вести после многочисленных замечаний? Не должно быть неприкасаемых. Иначе посыплются обвинения в элитаризме.

Comment: _"И ты прав. И ты прав"._

Comment: а у участников с репутацией в Nк - депутатская неприкосновенность должна быть?)

Comment: @Denis, сроки блокировки определяются системой и увеличиваются из бана в бан.

Comment: @Nofate, что-то имеете против избранных любимчиков?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Забавно, но именно о такой ситуации был первый вопрос к кандидатам на выборах в модераторы StackOverflow на русском:

> Как вы поступите с участником, который создает большое количество ценных ответов, но порождает массу споров в комментариях, которые впоследствии отмечаются сигналом тревоги?

[Ознакомьтесь с мнениями](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2147/181100), обратите внимание на голоса сообщества у каждого из них. Правда, ответы там от каждого участника на все вопросы от сообщества сразу. Поэтому голоса, возможно, слабо отражают поддержку сообществом ответов именно на него.

В целом, кандидаты (кроме одного, чьи ответы получили наименьший рейтинг) склоняются к тому, что блокировки как меры пресечения надо до последнего избегать, но если больше ничего не работает или мирные способы разрешить конфликт не находятся (например, если конфликт перерос в неконструктивную перепалку), то это единственный выход.

Discord, ныне Squidward, [неплохо сформулировал, почему](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2152/181100):

> В конечном счёте, неприкосновенных нет. Даже если у участника 100К репутации, он может быть забанен на какое-то время, чтобы остыть и подумать о своём поведении. Нарушение правил есть нарушение, и ценные ответы не могут служить оправданием. Появление "высшей касты" может привести к гораздо большему вреду, чем обида одного конфликтного участника: уйдёт не один "супер-участник", а 20 "средних".

---

Но там совершенно не затронут вопрос о *длительности* блокировки.

Хотя с этим как раз всё просто. Задача не только устранить сиюминутную драму, но и предотвратить их дальнейшее возникновение, чтобы свести к минимуму необходимость в модераторских вмешательствах в будущем. **Поэтому каждое следующее наказание за аналогичное нарушение должно быть существенно больше предыдущего**, т. к. предыдущего было, очевидно, недостаточно.